# Prove that finite sets are closed

Tags: general-topology

How would you prove that finite sets are closed? This is what I have now but it seems too simple:
Let $A$ be a finite set where $A = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ for some $n\in N$. Let $\hat A = \emptyset$.  $\emptyset$ is open and thus by the definition, $A$ is closed.

Is there any way to prove this using the $\delta$ -neighborhood definition?

Comment: Thank you BaronVT for helping me with those MathJax symbols

Comment: No problem - you had them mostly right: just add a `$` before and after something to typeset (`$x\in A$` becomes $x\in A$), and use `\{` and `\}` for curly braces.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that a single point is closed (as a set), then any finite set is closed because they are finite unions of closed (single point) sets.

Comment: And that a singleton set in the standard topology is closed could be easily seen by noting that a set is closed iff every convergent sequence in this set has its limit also in the set, and for a singleton set each sequence in the set is constant, i.e. equal to the only element.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of background set/topology are working with?

If we're talking about $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then, for every point $x \not\in A$, we can be sure that

$$
\delta := \min\{|x - x_n|:x_n \in A\} > 0
$$

so we are guaranteed that $B_{\delta}(x) \cap A = \emptyset$.

Comment: This is an undergrad course and we are just getting introduced to elementary topology of ℝ.

Comment: Ok, then the argument I gave applies.